# Restore of backup db failed.(Microsoft.SqlServer. Management.RelationalEngingeTasks)

Tags: database-restore

System. Data.Sqlclient.SqlError:This backup  set cannot be applied because it is on a recovery path that is inconsistent with the database. The recovery path is the sequence of data and log backup that have brought the database to a particular recovery point. Find compatible backup to restore,or restore the rest of the database to match recovery point within this backup set, which will restore database to a different point in time. For more information about recovery paths, see SQL server server books online.

I try to restore differential backup in existing database